# Bash Script Detects Key Down At Boot

Tags: boot, init-script

I want to customize my run level scripts based upon a key combo pressed at boot.

How to I test for key presses as early as possible from boot?  Do I need to do something special, like for example: lock the computer at run level 1 so I can prepare run level 5 scripts?

How do I go about this?

Comment: Which OS/distro?

Comment: Linux Mint Julia 10.04 based on Ubuntu

Comment: Can't you use different grub menus?

Comment: Is it possible to make grub mv config files before it begins the boot process?  I haven't found anything after looking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read -N 1 -t 0.1` to try and capture a keypress in your sysinit script (`/etc/rc.sysinit` here, dunno what it is on Mint) and switch to the appropriate runlevel based on the captured character.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1573

Comment: How would that look in a script?  I'm having trouble just getting it to work on the command line.